# Redefinition of 'int str_find(char*, char*)' error

Tags: c

I am trying to run the following code:

Main C file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_functions.c"
#include "my_functions.h"

int main(int argv, char **argc) {
    for (int i = 0; i < argv; i++)
        printf("%s\n", argc[i]);
    printf("%d\n", str_find("=", "-h=123"));
    printf("%d\n", str_find("xyx", "aaaa"));
    return 0;
}
```

Included .c file for Main **.c** file from local Library / my_functions.c file

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "my_functions.h"

int str_length(char *mystring) {

    int i = 0;

    while (*mystring != '\0') {

        i++;

        mystring++;
    }

    return i;
}
```

Included .h file for Main .c file from local Library / my_functions.h file

```
#ifndef MyFunctions_h
#define MyFunctions_h
#include <stdio.h>

void str_copy(char *destination, char *source) {
    while (*source != '\0') {
        *destination = *source; 
        source++; 
        destination++;
    }
    *destination = '\0';
}

#endif

int str_find(char *needle, char *haystack) {
    int i = 0;
    int c = 0;
    while (*needle != '\0') {
        ++i;
        ++needle;
    }

    needle -= i;

    while (*haystack != '\0') {
        ++c;
        ++haystack;
    }

    haystack -= c;

    int k = 0;
    int sp = 0;
   
    for (int d = 0; d <= c; ++d, ++haystack)
    {
        if (*haystack == *needle && k == 0)
        {
            sp = d;
            ++k;
            ++needle;
        } else if (*haystack != *needle && k != 0)
        {
            needle -= k;
            k = 0;
        }
    }
    
    if (sp == 0) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return sp;
    }
}
```

Here is the error I am receiving in the Output in Visual Studio Code, which comes from the imported my_functions.h file and the `int str_find(char *needle, char *haystack)` function:

```
redefinition of 'int str_find(char*, char*)'
```

I am unable to resolve this issue on my own and need help.

What needs to be done to solve this issue, so my code can run properly?

Comment: It's very rare to `#include` a `.c` file.  Why are you doing that?

Comment: Hey, @StephenNewell

I was asked to include both .c / .h files in the main file as per the requirements of a task I am required to complete

Comment: Can you please share the exact contents for `my_functions.h` and `my_functions.c`? Headers most likely should contain only the definition of a function and the c file their declaration

Comment: Hey, @malatindez

I've edited the post, you can see which parts of the code are from my_functions.h and my_functions.c file now.

Comment: @onix012 Do you have main defined in `my_functions.c`? If so, you have recursive header inclusion error.

Comment: I've updated the my_functions.c file, please check now

Comment: @malatindez You've got the terms swapped. A function can be **declared** many times (and all declarations must match), but can only be **defined** once for the linker to sleep easy at night. **declare** is the prototype; **define** is the meat & potatoes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you did not guard definition of the `str_find`.
`main.c` includes `my_functions.c` that includes `my_functions.h` and therefore definition `str_find`.
After that, you include `my_functions.h` that defines `str_find` again.

To fix that just move `#endif` to the bottom of `my_functions.h`

Comment: Good, but... A function **definition** can be its own **declaration**. This OP shows the multiple #include's (with executable code in .h file and #include of .c) have resulted in attempting to **redefine** the function... That is what the compiler error message is saying, "redefinition of ..." Too many people get these two terms swapped.

Answer (score 0):

You have a redefinition of the function `str_find()` because it is defined in **my_functions.h** and **my_functions.h** is included twice in the **main.c** file, once directly via `#include "my_functions.h"` and another time indirectly via `#include "my_functions.c"`.

You should not put function *definitions* in the header file **my_functions.h**. You should only have function *prototypes* and structure, type and macro definitions in header files. The function *definitions* belong in **my_functions.c**, which correctly includes **my_functions.h** for consistency checking.

Regarding the **main.c** source file: you should

- either include only **my_functions.h** and compile and link both **main.c** and **my_functions.c** together.
- or include **my_functions.c** as you did to compile a single source file.
- or include both to compile the `main` function using the function declarations from **my_functions.h** and append the contents of **my_functions.c** to allow compiling a single source file into an executable, but this is not recommended.

Here are modified versions of your files:

**my_functions.h**:

```
int str_length(char *mystring);
void str_copy(char *destination, char *source);
int str_find(char *needle, char *haystack);
```

**my_functions.c**:

```
#include "my_functions.h"

int str_length(char *mystring) {
    int i = 0;

    while (*mystring != '\0') {
        i++;
        mystring++;
    }
    return i;
}

void str_copy(char *destination, char *source) {
    while (*source != '\0') {
        *destination = *source; 
        source++; 
        destination++;
    }
    *destination = '\0';
}

int str_find(char *needle, char *haystack) {
    int i = 0;
    int c = 0;

    while (*needle != '\0') {
        ++i;
        ++needle;
    }

    needle -= i;

    while (*haystack != '\0') {
        ++c;
        ++haystack;
    }

    haystack -= c;

    int k = 0;
    int sp = 0;
   
    for (int d = 0; d <= c; ++d, ++haystack) {
        if (*haystack == *needle && k == 0) {
            sp = d;
            ++k;
            ++needle;
        } else if (*haystack != *needle && k != 0) {
            needle -= k;
            k = 0;
        }
    }
    
    if (sp == 0) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return sp;
    }
}
```

**main.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_functions.h"

int main(int argv, char **argc) {
    for (int i = 0; i < argv; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", argc[i]);
    }
    printf("%d\n", str_find("=", "-h=123"));
    printf("%d\n", str_find("xyx", "aaaa"));
    printf("%d\n", str_find("aab", "aaab"));
    return 0;
}

#include "my_functions.c"
```

Note also these remarks:

- the argument strings that are not modified in the functions should be defined as `const char *`.
- the definition of `str_find()` is bogus: it will fail many simple test cases.  You should return as soon as you have a complete match in the main loop and backtrack to the next character in `haystack` when the match fails.  There is no real gain in computing the lengths of the strings, especially `needle` whose length you compute in `i` and never use.

Here is a modified version:

```
int str_find(const char *needle, const char *haystack) {
    if (*needle == '\0') {
        // special case the empty needle, return the beginning of haystack
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; haystack[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (haystack[i] == needle[j]) {
            j++;
            if (needle[j] == '\0') {
                // we have a match, return the offset of the first character
                return i + 1 - j;
            }
        } else {
            i -= j;  // backtrack to start of match
            j = 0;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```